# Split View in Cocoa Apps

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, macos, ios

Does anybody know of any XCode extensions or ways to create the Split View based application seen in Cocoa Touch in Cocoa for use in a Mac application?

Examples I've seen are "Reeder for mac" and the latest Twitter Application in the App Store.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cocoa has an `NSSplitView` class which can be used in Interface Builder, and you can always create custom split views or use open source ones such as [RBSplitView](http://brockerhoff.net/src/rbs.html) or the one available in [BWToolkit](http://brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/).

Comment: Note that BWToolkit, and possibly RBSplitView as well, make use of private frameworks. Using them may keep your application from being accepted into the Mac App Store, if that's your ultimate goal.

Comment: @craig: Are you saying that those items use private APIs in Apple's frameworks, thereby disqualifying them, or that an application sold in the Mac App Store cannot use secondary frameworks (for example, residing in AppName.app/Contents/Frameworks inside the application bundle)? While the former may or may not be true, the latter isn't true; the restriction of third-party frameworks only applies to the iPhone app store. For example, TextWrangler.app uses Growl.framework.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the former. I spoke with the developer of BWToolkit a couple months ago, and he confirmed that BWToolkit does use private frameworks. (As such I had to remove it before submitting my app to the Mac App Store.) I'm not sure about RBSplitView, but I would recommend that the OP get as far as he can with the available AppKit classes, and add custom functionality if he really needs it. (And if he does need it, contact the developer to find out if private frameworks are being used.)

Comment: As the author of RBSplitView I can confirm that it uses no private APIs (or private frameworks, either).

Answer (score 2):

**What additional functionality are you looking for that isn't provided by the already-available NSSplitView?**

Reeder for Mac seems to use a simple NSSplitView with 3 subviews. (To create a split view with 3 views, drag the usual NSSplitView into a window or view in InterfaceBuilder, then drag an additional NSView into the NSSplitView in the "Outline Mode" of your IB document's window.)

Comment: Learning that a split view may have 3 subviews is gold for me right now. Thanks! :-)